# Inner Join and Count throwing up errors

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g

I am still a bit of a newbie when it comes to SQL and I am wondering if you can assist. I have been asked to join two tables (which I assumed was an inner join) and count and group the results.

The code I have written is:

```
SELECT publisher.name, printjob.JobNo, r.CountPO
    FROM Publisher, PrintJob
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT purchaseorder.orderno count (*) as CountPO, FROM purchaseorder
GROUPBY publisher.name) as r ON 
as ORDER BY publisher.name;
```

But it states that FROM is not where it is supposed to be. I am not sure if thats the case, any advice would be much appreciated.

Ta!

EDIT: Ok, I have corrected the above to:

SELECT PrintJob.JobNo, count (*) as POS FROM PurchaseOrder INNER JOIN PrintJob WHERE purchaseorder.printjob = printjob.jobno GROUP BY publisher.name;

Still gotten nowhere.

*cries*

Comment: there should be a a space after `GROUP` - `GROUPBY` . missing comma between orderno and count(*) . Also, what is the join condition between `Publisher` and  `PrintJob`?

Comment: So many errors: Do **not** mix implicit joins and explicit `JOIN` operators. `GROUPBY` should be `GROUP BY`, remove the `,` after `CountPO` before the `FROM`. Remove the `as` for the table alias. `ON as ... ` is missing something as well.

Comment: Oh dear. :( 

I will amend the above, but it does not seem like its going very well today.

Comment: SELECT publisher.name, printjob.JobNo, r.CountPO
FROM Publisher, PrintJob
INNER JOIN  (SELECT purchaseorder.orderno, count (*) as CountPO FROM purchaseorder
GROUP BY publisher.name) r ON 
ORDER BY publisher.name;


Its still not impressed.

Answer (score 1):

you have coma in wrong place:

```
SELECT purchaseorder.orderno, count (*) as CountPO FROM purchaseorder
GROUPBY publisher.name
```

And you need group by in inner query.
And you need some join condition after ON.

Also it is not nice to use 2 types of join in one query:

```
FROM Publisher, PrintJob
```

should do everywhere via join:

```
FROM Publisher as p
inner join PrintJob as pj on [some condition]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT purchaseorder.orderno count (*) as CountPO, FROM purchaseorder
GROUPBY publisher.name) as r ON [some condition]
```

Comment: Thank you, I have amended the above :)